# R: How to count the number of occurrences of a value across multiple columns?

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of times each variable occurs across two separate columns.
Similar to:

```
var1    var2    var3
a       b       a
c       c       a
b       a       b
```

I want to know the number of times each variable occurs in the columns var1 and var2. The output should look something like

```
var   count
a     3
b     2
c     1
```

I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow but haven't seemed to find one that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may `subset` the columns, `unlist` to a `vector` and get the `table` in `base R`, `stack` it to a two column data.frame if needed

```
stack(table(unlist(df1[c("var1", "var2")])))[2:1]`
```

---

Or with packages, reshape to 'long' using `pivot_longer` and get the `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    select(var1, var2) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = NULL, values_to = 'var') %>%
    count(var, name = "count")
```